# How to make a CSS-like button animation React

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native

On click of a button, I would like a small sparkle to appear and disappear, in about a half-second's timeframe.

I have considered using a gif, but it requires significant manual artistic effort to get a satisfying effect.

Is there a way to use the Animation module or any third-party library to animate precise effects?

The limit of Animated module seems to be simple translation and opacity animations, which I have an example of written below:

```
    <Animated.View
      style={{
        position: 'absolute',
        zIndex: 900,
        bottom: constants.NAVBARHEIGHT / 4,
        height: 90,
        opacity: fade,
        width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
      }}>
```

but I have no idea how to get more complex animations like shown here: https://codepen.io/mccombsc/pen/ZEzxWPy

Comment: Its going to require (very moderate) artistic effort by someone in some regard. use an open source icon or clip art library like nounproject to do it yourself.

Comment: thanks for the help. does nounproject have animations? i can only see static images.

Comment: It doesnt, I suggest using those icons to create the animation you are describing. Look into using css animations to do this.

Comment: oh, i see. i will do that. thank you!

Comment: so i've found lottie and keyframes that seem to do what i want. i'm not sure how they work. do i have first have to make animations in aftereffects?

Comment: nvm, found a place i can download them. thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use lottie animation
Working example: https://snack.expo.io/@msbot01/forlorn-raspberries

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import LottieView from 'lottie-react-native';




export default class NoNetwork extends Component {

  handleClick(){
    console.log('>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>.')
    this.animation.play();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor:'white', justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center' }}>
        
        <LottieView 
        source={require('./circle2.json')} 
        ref={animation => {
          this.animation = animation;
        }} 
        autoPlay={false}  
        loop={false}/>
      <TouchableOpacity style={{height:50, width:150, backgroundColor:'#8fd8ff', borderRadius:10, justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center'}} onPress={()=>{this.handleClick()}}><Text style={{color:'#31789e'}}>Click me</Text></TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    ); 
  } 
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({});
```